# Cakephp : add condition in this->Model->save()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x .want to add a condition into my save query .. for example i want to implement this query

```
       INSERT INTO 'this' where condition is 'this'
```

right now i am doing this

```
      $count = $this->Message->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array('Message.mobileNo' => $mobileNo,
                                      'Message.body'=>$body

                )));

            if($count>0){
                echo "already have a message";

             }else
            {
                $this->Message->create();
                $this->Message->save($this->request->data);
            }
```

at times now i am first checking through count and then saving into the database ... can i add condition into my **save**  so i dont have to query two times into database just to accomplish one task

Comment: Why not using a custom validation rule for this in the model? Would be way cleaner: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

This is not really CakePHP question rather than MySQL. But you can't do this since the [INSERT query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) doesn't have conditional query.

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1. As Mark in the comment said use validation. The validation although apply to single field, so it will be quite tricky to do it.
2. Use beforeValidate() or beforeSave() callbacks in your model to check this and if they return false the save operation wont be executed.
3. You can put UNIQUE index to your table so it won't allow insertion of phone+message together.

I would go with the method 2.

Answer (score 0):

try the `beforeSave` methode in your Model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in a better way:

```
$conditions = array('Message.mobileNo' => $mobileNo,
            'Message.body'=>$body);
if ($this->Message->hasAny($conditions)){
    echo "already have a message";
}
else{
    $this->Message->create();
        $this->Message->save($this->request->data);
}
```